# Need help in 'App purchase programming guide' for iphone!

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have read the document for 'App purchase programming guide'. I am confused. It seems it does not apply to my circumstances. My apps is 'nonconsumable' type (purchase only once to use the apps) and the feature delivery is 'built-in product model' no server whatsoever. I also had added the storekit.framework. My question is do I need to add any additional coding? Based on the document it gives some sample code. Do I really need that for my case?

Comment: If you are just selling an app through the app store, you don't have to do anything.  Only if you want to allow the user to make additional purchases FROM WITHIN your app do you need to implement any of the in-app purchase code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you want to utilize In App Purchases, you can't just build against StoreKit.framework to your project. You need to create a UI so users can purchase items, which means you'll need to write code.

Comment: Hi, 
I got this link from other people similar question. [link](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/comment-page-1/#comments)
I am at step no 7. but how it will trigger the function? so I can see the NSLog.

Comment: You trigger the function using your interface. You create an interface that will trigger the function somehow.